# User resizable image in jquery and save new dimensions with submit button to mysql for later use

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am calling an image with preset dimensions from a mysql database (this part works fine) and then providing the 'resizable' jquery library giving the user the ability to resize an image within a set area without having to press a submit button. The image resizes fine so everything is working there.

Unfortunately I cannot get the new dimensions to save to the database so on refresh the size goes back to the default size I have set, I have been searching for quite a while now on a solution and I am not too strong on ajax and jquery.

Can anyone help?

```
var startW = ('<?php echo "$w_pos";?>');
var startH = ('<?php echo "$h_pos";?>');

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.resizable').resizable({

start : function(event,ui) {
    startW = $(this).outerWidth();
    startH = $(this).outerHeight();
},
stop : function(event,ui) {
    endW = $(this).outerWidth();
    endH = $(this).outerHeight();
    alert("Width changed:"+ (startW + ' to ' + endW) + " and Height changed:" + (startH + ' to ' + endH));
    $.post('updatedimensions.php', { endW: 'endW', endH: 'endH' });
}
});
});
```

updatedimensions.php

```
if(isset($_POST['endW'])){$w_coord=$_POST['endW']}
if(isset($_POST['endH'])){$h_coord=$_POST['endH']}

//Setup Query
$sql = "UPDATE images SET h_pos = '$h_coord', w_pos = '$w_coord' where id = ".$id."";

//Execute Query
mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Error updating Coords :".mysqli_error());
```

Comment: You are not sending your variables/data, you are sending `endW` and `endH` literal, try removing the quotes -> `$.post('updatedimensions.php', { endW: endW, endH: endH });`. Also, where are you setting `$id` in your query -> `where id = ".$id."`?

Comment: Sean, thanks heaps for the help, the quotes where stopping it from working.